# Open Jquery dialog based on mouse location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

Is it possible to open a jquery dialog when a mouse moves over a certain area of a page?
I do not want the box to be attached to the cursor, just if a user moves towards the browser close button, can I open a jquery digalog or window in the center of the page?

I've tried to search answers, but mostly have dialogs that are attached the mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Have a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3a0J3fqbESMzzVJi412Q?p=preview) to get an idea how to start implement it.
Basically, you listen for mousemove event on the entire document, when the mouse cursor is between your desired boundaries (top right corner - 50px on x and - 50px on y in demo), you show up the dialog and then unbind the mousemove event for performance reasons.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('mousemove.closebtn', function(e) {
        var xOffsetToTest = 50,
            yOffsetToTest = 50,
            windowWidth = $(window).width(),
            dialog = $('#dialog');

        if (e.pageX > (windowWidth - xOffsetToTest) &&
            e.pageY < (windowWidth - yOffsetToTest)) {
            $("#dialog").dialog();
            $(document).off('mousemove.closebtn');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If I wanted to use the full width of the browser, will I have to create a div so I can have a certain height?

Comment: actually i just bind hover on a div and it seems to work